# How to change color for each classification in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I am making a scatter plot matrix using R. But I want to change the color for each classification. So far I can only change the color of everything, not selectively.

There are only 2 classification (Either 1 or 0 in the N column)  but I have 300++ data, if possible, is there a way not to manually change the color of each data point?

I searched through the web but so far I cant find any material that would clearly teach me about it

Here is my code so far:

```
pairs(data[2:14], pch = 20, col = 'blue')
```

This is the head(data) of my csv for reference

```
data <- read.table(text="
A B         C         D         E F G         H I         J   K         L    M N
1 0.63 1 0.0000000 0.4811321 0.2442922 1 1 0.6030534 0 0.3709677 1.0 0.0000000 0.75 0
2 0.67 1 1.0000000 0.6226415 0.3652968 0 1 0.2824427 1 0.2419355 0.5 1.0000000 0.00 1
3 0.67 1 1.0000000 0.2452830 0.2351598 0 1 0.4427481 1 0.4193548 0.5 0.6666667 1.00 1
4 0.37 1 0.6666667 0.3396226 0.2831050 0 0 0.8854962 0 0.5645161 1.0 0.0000000 0.00 0
5 0.41 0 0.3333333 0.3396226 0.1780822 0 1 0.7709924 0 0.2258065 0.0 0.0000000 0.00 0
6 0.56 1 0.3333333 0.2452830 0.2511416 0 0 0.8167939 0 0.1290323 0.0 0.0000000 0.00 0")
```

Comment: A simple fix is `pairs(data[2:14], pch = 20, col = data$N+1)`. (I added 1 here because you have 0/1 and R starts it's color at 1 rather than 0.)

Comment: This is done in the first example in `?pairs` . Provided you have `ggplot2` and `GGally`, you can could try`ggpairs(data, columns = 2:14, aes(colour = N))`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to plot pairs is using the base R function.

```
pairs(data[2 : 14], 
          pch = 20, col = c("red", "blue")[data$N + 1])
```

One can easily color the points as well as have different shapes.

Although it is not so easy,  there are other packages that can do better. One option is to use the `ggplot2` and the `GGally` combination.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)
```

With this option, you have colours can not be a numeric.

```
data$N <- as.factor(data$N)
```

Then the following would give a pairs plot with more info.

```
ggpairs(data, columns = 2:14, 
  mapping = ggplot2::aes(color = N))
```

There are number of other ways one can manipulate upper and lower parts of the pairs plot using `GGally`. Following is an example using the examples in `?ggpairs`.

```
ggpairs(data, columns = 2:14, 
        mapping = ggplot2::aes(color = N),
  upper = list(continuous = wrap("density", alpha = 0.5), 
               combo = "box_no_facet"),
  lower = list(continuous = wrap("points", alpha = 0.3), 
               combo = wrap("dot_no_facet", alpha = 0.4))
)
```

Another cool I liked a lot about this package is it's `putPlot` function which lets you insert/put your own plots into the pairs layout.